# Defining arrays in Delphi, for use with Windows API and COM+ interfaces

Tags: arrays, delphi, interface, com+

In the Windows Known Folders API, IKnownFolderManager::GetFolderIds is defined as:

```cpp
HRESULT GetFolderIds([out] KNOWNFOLDERID **ppKFId, [in, out] UINT *pCount);
```

After a successful call, ppKFId points to an array of KNOWNFOLDERIDs (GUIDs), which the caller must eventually free using CoTaskMemFree - so far, so standard.

The Delphi version in ShlObj.pas (Delphi Alexandria 11.2) is defined as:

```pascal
function GetFolderIds(ppKFId: array of TKnownFolderID; var pCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

where TKnownFolderId types to a TGUID.

My question is how do I define a variable in Delphi that will satisfy both the "array of TKnownFolderID" parameter, but still be able to free the array with CoTaskMemFree (which requires a pointer)?

What I've tried:

```pascal
var FolderList: array of TKnownFolderID;
```

Gets a protection exception because Delphi passes the contents of FolderList (nil) instead of the address of FolderList (which is what I'd expect, since a dynamic array under Delphi is a pointer).

```pascal
type FolderListType = array of KNOWNFOLDERID;
var FolderList: FolderListType;
```

produces exactly the same result, as you'd expect.

```pascal
var FolderList: array[0..0] of KNOWNFOLDERID;
```

gives a compiler error on the CoTaskMemFree, because array[0..0] is not a pointer. Typecasting FolderList to a pointer fails with "invalid typecast".

```pascal
type
FolderListType = array of KNOWNFOLDERID;
PFolderListType = ^FolderListType;
var
FolderList: PFolderListType;
```

gives a compiler error on the GetFolderIDs with incompatible types.

```pascal
type FolderListType = array of KNOWNFOLDERID;
var FolderList: FolderListType;
begin
  SetLength(FolderList, 1000);
...GetFolderIds(FolderList, ...
```

fails with a protection exception, as does GetFolderIds(FolderList[0],...

```pascal
type
  FolderListType = array[0..0] of KNOWNFOLDERID;
  FolderListRec = record
  case boolean of
    true: (FL: FolderListType);
    false: (FLP: pointer);
  end;
var
  FolderListPointer: PKNOWNFOLDERID;
  FolderList: array of FolderListRec;
begin
  FolderList.FLP := @FolderListPointer;
  GetFolderIds(FolderList.FL,...
```

fails with a protection exception.

```pascal
var
  FolderListPointer: PKNOWNFOLDERID;
  FolderList: array of KNOWNFOLDERID;
begin
  pointer(FolderList) := @FolderListPointer;
  ...GetFolderIds(FolderList, ...);
  ...
  CoTaskMemFree(FolderListPointer);
  pointer(FolderList) := nil;
```

retrieves the list of Known Folders successfully, but perculiarly the second parameter (count of Known Folders) is untouched. However, I *really* don't like typecasting dynamic arrays to pointers like this.

Overriding the supplied definition of IKnownFolderManager.GetFolderIDs to

```pascal
function GetFolderIds(var ppKFId: PKnownFolderID; var pCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

and using

```pascal
var FolderList: PKnownFolderID;
begin
  ...GetFolderIds(FolderList, ...);
```

works fine. Compiles cleanly, retrieves the list and the count perfectly, and CoTaskMemFree is happy.

So, am I, through a lack of knowledge, missing something about defining Delphi vars that would work in this situation, or is it just a bad translation from the Windows header? I work with interfaces in Delphi a lot, and frequently find what I consider to be poor translations (such as an optional out parameter being defined as "var" instead of a pointer - which means you can't pass "nil", so under Delphi it's no longer optional) but I can't see a way of making this one, as defined, work at all, so it makes me wonder if I don't know Delphi as well as I thought I did.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration of `GetFolderIds()` in the `ShlObj` unit is wrong (and has been wrong since it was first introduced in D2010). It is not compatible with how the API works.

The API allocates a new array and returns a pointer to that array to the caller. An `array of ...` (aka, an [Open Array](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Open_Arrays)) parameter is NOT capable of receiving that pointer.

The correct declaration should have been this instead:

```pascal
function GetFolderIds(var ppKFId: PKnownFolderID; var pCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

And then, the proper usage would look like this:

```pascal
var
  FolderList: PKnownFolderID;
  Count: UINT;
begin
  ...
  OleCheck(Mgr.GetFolderIds(FolderList, Count));
  ...
  CoTaskMemFree(FolderList);
end;
```

I have reported this bug to Embarcadero:

[RSP-40106: Declaration of IKnownFolderManager.GetFolderIds() in ShlObj.pas is wrong](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-40106)

Until Embarcadero fixes this in `ShlObj`, you are going to have to copy the declaration of the `IKnownFolderManager` interface into your own code and fix the mistake there, and then use your copied interface as needed.